# Installing MySQL Ruby Gem

Tags: installation, mysql, ruby

Hi I am unsuccessfully trying to install MySQL Gem on Ubuntu 10.04.

I have tried the following commands:

```
sudo gem install mysql
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

I get the following message for each:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I've read on a lot of forums that installing MySQL client libraries (libmysqlclient-dev) helps fix the above issue, but it does for me.

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting libmysqlclient-dev instead of libmysqlclient15-dev
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help on what else may be the issue would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sharmil

Answer (score 14):

You just need to install `libmysqlclient-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

Does

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby
```

fetch the required gem?

Comment: +1 its better to use a ruby library from the repository if available. Use gems when the library is not packaged in the repository or if you need a specific version only available as a gem.